# Get previous week data from daily data dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 contains daily data

| Date | Week Day | High | Low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-2016 | Friday | 17144.85 | 16823 |
| 4-Jan-2016 | Monday | 17000 | 16603 |
| 5-Jan-2016 | Tuesday | 16700 | 16516.65 |
| 6-Jan-2016 | Wednesday | 16659.3 | 16376 |
| 7-Jan-2016 | Thursday | 16344.4 | 16058 |
| 8-Jan-2016 | Friday | 16264 | 16126.05 |
| 11-Jan-2016 | Monday | 16186 | 15841.4 |
| 12-Jan-2016 | Tuesday | 16125.3 | 15723.3 |
| 13-Jan-2016 | Wednesday | 15974 | 15536 |
| 14-Jan-2016 | Thursday | 15808.7 | 15455 |
| 15-Jan-2016 | Friday | 15639 | 15161.5 |
| 18-Jan-2016 | Monday | 15347 | 14985.35 |
| 19-Jan-2016 | Tuesday | 15348 | 15083.65 |
| 20-Jan-2016 | Wednesday | 15060 | 14730 |
| 21-Jan-2016 | Thursday | 15360 | 14901 |
| 22-Jan-2016 | Friday | 15607.8 | 15261 |
| 25-Jan-2016 | Monday | 15681.3 | 15460 |
| 27-Jan-2016 | Wednesday | 15629.2 | 15412.65 |
| 28-Jan-2016 | Thursday | 15564.9 | 15355 |
| 29-Jan-2016 | Friday | 15578 | 15171.6 |

what I want to do is based on df1 need to create a new dataframe and store the previous week  cumulative High and Low for the selected week.

for Current week High and Low (CWH and CWL) columns it store the current week high/low for each date of the week in a way the each date of the week hold the value like Max(starting date of week, selected dated of week) and mark None to each starting day of the week

**for example :**
lets take Week 1 is 4th jan - 8th Jan, Week 2 is 11th Jan - 15 Jan , Week 1 is not having any previous week so in new dataframe for all the dates from 4th to 8th will hold None In previous High/Low column. Week2 previous week is week 1 so all dates of week 2 will hold max of High and Min of Low.

Current CWH and CWL:
in week 1 4th jan is the starting day of week so marked as None,
5th Jan is the max(4th, 5th), 6th jan max(4th, 6th) and so on for all weeks

Expected Output:

| Date | PWH | PWL | CWH | CWL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-2016 | - | - | - | - |
| 4-Jan-2016 | 17144.85 | 16823 | - | - |
| 5-Jan-2016 | 17144.85 | 16823 | 17000 | 16603 |
| 6-Jan-2016 | 17144.85 | 16823 | 17000 | 16516.65 |
| 7-Jan-2016 | 17144.85 | 16823 | 17000 | 16376 |
| 8-Jan-2016 | 17144.85 | 16823 | 17000 | 16058 |
| 11-Jan-2016 | 17000 | 16058 | - | - |
| 12-Jan-2016 | 17000 | 16058 | 16186 | 15841.4 |
| 13-Jan-2016 | 17000 | 16058 | 16186 | 15723.3 |
| 14-Jan-2016 | 17000 | 16058 | 16186 | 15536 |
| 15-Jan-2016 | 17000 | 16058 | 16186 | 15455 |
| 18-Jan-2016 | 16186 | 15161.5 | - | - |
| 19-Jan-2016 | 16186 | 15161.5 | 15347 | 14985.35 |
| 20-Jan-2016 | 16186 | 15161.5 | 15348 | 14985.35 |
| 21-Jan-2016 | 16186 | 15161.5 | 15348 | 14730 |
| 22-Jan-2016 | 16186 | 15161.5 | 15360 | 14730 |
| 25-Jan-2016 | 15607.8 | 14730 | - | - |
| 27-Jan-2016 | 15607.8 | 14730 | 15681.3 | 15460 |
| 28-Jan-2016 | 15607.8 | 14730 | 15681.3 | 15412.65 |
| 29-Jan-2016 | 15607.8 | 14730 | 15681.3 | 15355 |

Tried this code:

```
temp_wk = daily_df.copy()
temp_wk.set_index(pd.to_datetime(temp_wk['Date']), inplace=True)

weekly_high = temp_wk['Low'].resample('W').min()

prev_week_high = weekly_high.shift(1)

print(prev_week_high)
```

But this is not giving accepted output.

Comment: Why does your expected output not have a value for `PWL` and `PWH` for the first week of the year (January 4th to 8th)? Is it because January 1st is part of the last week of the previous year? If so you should edit your question to mention it.

Comment: @rorshan because there is no previous week for week 4th - 8th.

Comment: Why is the first row timestamped `1-Jan-2016` not the previous week ? Any elegant solution will by default consider `1-Jan-2016` to be part of the previous week.

Comment: @rorshan that's fine no issues with that, edited my expected output, 1 jan can be considered previous week

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': daily_df['Date'], 'PWH': None, 'PWL': None, 'CWH': None, 'CWL': None})

new_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(new_df['Date'])
new_df['Week'] = new_df['Date'].dt.week

# Compute the cumulative high and low for the previous week, and fill in the appropriate values
for week in new_df['Week'].unique():
    if week == new_df['Week'].min():
        # Skip the first week, since there is no previous week
        continue
    prev_week_mask = new_df['Week'] == (week - 1)
    curr_week_mask = new_df['Week'] == week
    prev_week_high = daily_df.loc[prev_week_mask, 'High'].max()
    prev_week_low = daily_df.loc[prev_week_mask, 'Low'].min()
    new_df.loc[curr_week_mask, 'PWH'] = prev_week_high
    new_df.loc[curr_week_mask, 'PWL'] = prev_week_low

# Compute the current week high and low, and fill in the appropriate values
for week in new_df['Week'].unique():
    week_mask = new_df['Week'] == week
    start_date = new_df.loc[week_mask, 'Date'].min()
    for i, row in new_df.loc[week_mask].iterrows():
        if row['Date'] == start_date:
            # For the starting date of the week, set the current week high and low to None
            new_df.loc[i, 'CWH'] = None
            new_df.loc[i, 'CWL'] = None
        else:
            # For other dates in the week, set the current week high and low to the max/min of the previous values and the current values
            prev_high = new_df.loc[i-1, 'CWH']
            prev_low = new_df.loc[i-1, 'CWL']
            curr_high = daily_df.loc[daily_df['Date'] == row['Date'], 'High'].values[0]
            curr_low = daily_df.loc[daily_df['Date'] == row['Date'], 'Low'].values[0]
            new_df.loc[i, 'CWH'] = max(prev_high, curr_high)
            new_df.loc[i, 'CWL'] = min(prev_low, curr_low)

# Drop the Week column to match expected output
new_df.drop(columns=['Week'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: previous week part worked like charm but for current week it throws error index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
at curr_high = temp_wk.loc[temp_wk['Date'] == row['Date'], 'High'].values[0]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date').sort_index()

#compute weekly min and max
week_max = df.resample('W')['High'].max()
week_min = df.resample('W')['Low'].min()


#compute weekly min and max
max_min = (df.resample('W')[['High', 'Low']]
           .agg({'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min'})
           .rename({'Low': 'PWL', 'High':'PWH'}, axis=1)
           .shift(1)
           )
max_min.index = max_min.index - timedelta(weeks=1)

#merge_asof will perform a join based on the closest date, in the backward direction
df = pd.merge_asof(df, max_min, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='backward')

#compute cumulative min and max in each week
df[['year','week', 'day']] = df.index.isocalendar()
#we also group by year in case we have multi-year data

#set `CWH` and `CWL` to the `High` and `Low` value of the first day of the week
df['CWH'] = df.groupby(['year','week'])['High'].transform('first')
df['CWL'] = df.groupby(['year','week'])['Low'].transform('first')

#perform max and min between the first day and current day
df['CWH'] = df[['High','CWH']].max(axis=1)
df['CWL'] = df[['Low','CWL']].min(axis=1)

#removing the first day of each week (weekdays were already sorted for merge_asof)
df.loc[df.groupby(['year','week']).head(1).index, ['CWH', 'CWL']] = None
df = df.drop(['High', 'Low', 'year', 'week', 'day', 'Week Day'], axis=1)
```

Comment: tried your code it works for previous week part but for current week values are misplace not matching with the expected output

Comment: The issue I have is that your expected output is not consistent with your formula. Can you confirm that `CWH = max(first day of the week, current day)` and `CWL = min(first day of the week, current day)` ? Right now the answer I gave was `CWH = max(all days of the week so far)` and `CWL = min(all days of the week so far)`, because it seemed more consistent with your erroneous expected output

Comment: For example, 12-Jan-2016 having a `CWL` of `16186` instead of `16125.3` does not make sense to me

Comment: I have edited my answer based on the `CWH = max(first day of the week, current day)` and `CWL = min(first day of the week, current day)` formulae